# Unable to reference another class library from within another library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a couple of class libraries called RogData that has a DB context class, and RogModleEntities that stores all of my entity classes. I need to reference from my RogData library the RogModleEntities library which I added a reference too.  I also have a using statement for RogModelEntities within the RogContext class show below.

After performing every known fix on Stackoverflow I'm still recieving this compile error "The type namespace 'some class name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)".

This is the DBcontext class from RogData library:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using RogModelEntities;

namespace RogData
{
     public class RogContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CurrentAddress> UserAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

And these are the two entity classes from RogModleEntities:

```
namespace RogModelEntities.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual CurrentAddress CurrentAddress { get; set; }

        public string PersonFullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
        }
   }
}

namespace RogModelEntities.Models
{
    public class CurrentAddress
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("PersonAddress")]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public Person PersonAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `using RogModelEntities.Models;`

Comment: @Khanh Wow... I never thought of that but I'm still wondering why since my entity classes are not located within a "Models" folder?

Comment: What matters is `namespace RogModelEntities.Models`, not where the files are located.

Comment: Yes I see now where your logic is coming from, and the problem came from adding these classes form another MVC project I had previously built. Thanks!

Comment: @Khan TO please add it as an answer, so it becomes easier for others who fall into similar problems

Comment: @gldraphael: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @gldraphael, I post as an answer.

Replace:

```
using RogModelEntities;
```

With:

```
using RogModelEntities.Models
```

Because your entities are inside RogModelEntities.Models. What matters is the code to declare the namespace: `namespace RogModelEntities.Models`, not where the files are located.